# Error de lógica casos no contemplados

Tags: c, algoritmos, lógica

Estaba resolviendo este problema de Omegaup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int ma[105][105];
    int ninos = 0, ninas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           scanf("%d", &ma[i][j]);
           if (j % 2 == 0)
           {
               ninas += ma[i][j];
           }
           else
           {
               ninos += ma[i][j];
           }
        }
     }
     if (ninas == ninos)
     {
       printf("Todos parejos.");
     }
     else if (ninas > ninos)
     {
        printf("Faltan %d alumnos.", (ninas - ninos));
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Faltan %d alumnas.", (ninos - ninas));
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

En general mi código funciona pero no del todo ya que al parecer falla en algunos casos por que solo me da 70/100.

Alguna sugerencia de algún caso qué no haya contemplado?

Comment: Prueba ingresando 3 grupos. Porque pide 5 veces? Ademas, no se porque vas
jugando con un array y tienes un loop adentro del otro. Simplemente lleva cuenta
de cuantos alumnos y cuantas alumnas hay. No guardes los datos en un array, crea
una variable temporal.

Comment: tenías razón, yo había entendido el problema de una manera diferente, gracias ya pude resolverlo!!